# How to use sed or awk to replace a pipe with a space, but only between alphabetic words

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I've been struggling with a script.  I have a list of gymnastics teams and scores.  I've managed to get the file pipe delimited, like the small example of data below.  However, now I need to replace the pipe with a space, but only if it is between alphabetic words.  A pipe between numbers must stay.  That way, I can have the team name, no matter how many words make it up, as one field.  The data will then be ready for loading in to my database.  I know `sed` or `awk` with regular expressions should be able to do this, but I'm not close to figuring it out.  I've messed with this all day and I'm sure someone can probably show me how to do it in 2 minutes. :-)

Starting format:

```
Twistars|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600
Excel|Gymnastics|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600
Head|Over|Heels|Gymnastics|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600
```

My end goal:

```
Twistars|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600
Excel Gymnastics|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600
Head Over Heels Gymnastics|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600
```

Any advice/small examples would be appreciated.

Comment: I hope you don't have any gymnasia with names such as `Fun|For|12|and|Under` where there's a number as part of the name. `Jones'|Gym` would cause trouble too.  Also, single letter words such as `A` can cause trouble too, in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk -F\| '{printf $1;for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf (($(i-1)!~/[0-9.]+/ && $(i)!~/[0-9.]+/)?" ":"|")"%s",$i;print ""}' file
Twistars|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600
Excel Gymnastics|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600
Head Over Heels Gymnastics|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600
```

Comment: Thank You!  It even works for gym names such as X - Treme Gymnastics or Wish upon a star, as the sed solution authors pointed out would be a problem with their sed/regex solutions above.  It's a winner and a keeper. - Bill

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/([[:alpha:]])\|([[:alpha:]])/\1 \2/g;ta' file
```

This replaces `|` between words with a space. A second sweep catches any matches missed on the first pass.

Answer (score 1):

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)|\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1 \2/g'  file
Twistars|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600
Excel Gymnastics|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600
Head Over Heels Gymnastics|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600
```

Comment: The only problem with this will be `Wish|Upon|A|Star|27.250|23.912|32.100|19.221|110.000`.  The pipe between `A` and `Star` won't be replaced. Any single-letter words in the middle of the name give this problem. I don't know of a better way to deal with it than to have the substitute command listed twice.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, great point. Can't think of a workaround for that case :-(

Comment: You probably need positive lookbehind and lookahead to match only the '|' conditionally and replace it with a space. Unfortunately, regular sed doesn't have that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the last 5 fields should not be joined:

```
awk '{p=$0; for(i=1;i<=NF-6;i++) sub(FS,OFS,p); print p}' FS='\\|' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'Excel|Gymnastics|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600' | sed 's/\([A-Za-z]\)\|\([A-Za-z]\)/\1 \2/g'
```

Output of the above

```
Excel Gymnastics|28.250|28.700|28.100|27.950|113.600
```

The above shows the basic `sed` expression you need. 
You can embellish in a few different ways.

```
cat file | sed 's/\([A-Za-z]\)\|\([A-Za-z]\)/\1 \2/g' > newFile

sed 's/\([A-Za-z]\)\|\([A-Za-z]\)/\1 \2/g' file > newfile
```

You can even use the "edit in place" flag with some versions of `sed` - this means you will write the file back in the same place:

```
sed -i 's/\([A-Za-z]\)\|\([A-Za-z]\)/\1 \2/g' file
```

Explanation:

```
\([A-Za-z]\)  capturing group: any character A-Z or a-z
\|            escaped pipe symbol (otherwise it means "or")
\([A-Za-z]\)  second capturing group: any character A-Z or a-z
```

we replace the above with

```
\1 \2         first captured group, space, second captured group

/g            global flag: do it for all occurrences
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)|\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1 \2/g'
```

works great except for the fact that single letters cause an issue:

```
$ echo 'Tete|A|Tete|4.489' | sed -e 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)|\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1 \2/g'
Tete A|Tete|4.489
```

This makes awk a better solution perhaps, though it is more verbose.

Since you already have a file, you can use ex:

```
printf '%%s/\\([[:alpha:]]\\)|\\([[:alpha:]]\\)/\\1 \\2/g\n%%&g\n%%p\n' | ex -s file >file2
```

Assuming you're using a shell supporting here-documents, you can make it more readable as the following:

```
ex -s file >file2 <<EOF
%s/\([[:alpha:]]\)|\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1 \2/g
%&g
%p
EOF
```

That just performs the same substitution as you would use with sed, except it allows you to repeat it using the & command. If you want it to simply modify the file in-place, drop the `>file2` and change `%p` to `w`:

```
ex -s file <<EOF
%s/\([[:alpha:]]\)|\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1 \2/g
%&g
w
EOF
```

There ought to be "a sed for ex" that makes the functionality of ex available for piped input just as sed does for ed, but I know of no such implementation currently. Emacs ships with a manpage suggesting such a utility exists, but the command isn't available and wouldn't do what ex does at all according to the manpage.